# Reach out to Clickatell

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

I just noticed an off-topic question, [Clickatell non-responsive support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815835/clickatell-non-responsive-support), on the main site asking about how to get Clickatell to respond to support requests.

If you go to http://www.clickatell.com and click on Contact Us->Ask the Community, you get a page inviting you to post a question here:
[image]

> Ask the community
>
> If you couldn't find the answer to your technical question in our FAQ section or developer section, Stack Overflow is the place to go. Ask questions, share insights, discuss new views, build connections, and learn from other developers in the Clickatell community.

Source: https://www.clickatell.com/contact/ask-the-community/

Suffice it to say, Stack Overflow is not the place for general technical support questions or "discussing" new views on Clickatell products.

Could someone reach out to Clickatell and ask them not to do this?

Comment: *build connections* because SO is just like LinkedIn... Well, it [kinda is](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs)... :)

Comment: "share insights, discuss new views" I think this blurb gives me permission to bash Clickatell using a "should be closed" flag's pole.

Comment: There's 56 questions tagged [tag:clickatell] ranging from pretty good to terrible.  Not sure if their staff are active on the tag, but this may just be a poor first question like so many others.

Comment: In fairness, it does says "your *technical* question". I don't know what Clickatell is (is it a programming tool?), but that seems like reasonable guidance, assuming anyone actually reads it. The problem here, of course, is the "share insights, discuss new views, build connections" part. That was obviously written by a marketing weasel who has no idea what a Q&A site does.

Comment: @RobertColumbia In case you don’t know, downvoting on meta is not like on the main site. Down/upvotes are used to express (dis-)agreement with the idea of the post.

Comment: @JonasWielicki the daily mantra. If only the tooltip on the downvote button would actually agree with what we use it for :/

Comment: @CodyGray: Clickatell is a messaging service, it allows for example to sens SMS to mobile phones in lots of countries. As a result, they expose a [Rest API](https://www.clickatell.com/developers/platform/api-documentation/). I guess some Rest questions could be about using Clickatell's API programmatically, which would be technical questions fitting Stack Overflow.

Comment: *"If you couldn't find the answer to your technical question..."* that seems pretty reasonable to me. The second sentence could be removed entirely.

Comment: @TinyGiant not all "technical questions" are [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. *Some* are, and certainly there's no problem in posting an MCVE related to the use of the Clickatell API. The problem with some of these product tags (e.g. Cloudberry) is that people post general questions about installing and configuring the software. Those are more Super User-type questions.

Comment: @RobertColumbia yeah not all technical questions are on-topic, but do we really have to make them include our entire on-topic help center section before they can refer people here? Re: MCVE, not all questions are debugging questions and only debugging questions require an MCVE. These are problems that are faced with *every* question, not just questions that were posted after it was suggested to a user that they "View Stack Overflow". I think that if the second sentence was removed and the link were to point to the on-topic section of the help center, that would be good enough.

Comment: @Gimby Agreed. Did you make a feature request for that (probably on SE meta)?

Comment: I agree that Clickatell should be contacted, but only to suggest that they handle direct support questions with a different channel. N.B. https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: @NH. no I didn't; I was and still am lazily assuming such a thing already exists, I can't believe I'm the first to bring that to the attention. But now that you reminded me I'm going to search for it later when I have the time.